# Invoke object methods in two different streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm not very used to Java streams, but basically I want to invoke different object methods after I retrieve data from the API in two different streams. I'm not sure how to do that, but here it is sort of the idea:

```
SimpleObject obj = new SimpleObject();

// stream1
StreamSupport
             .stream(myApi.getData())
             .map(myfunctions:function)
             // at this point I want to invoke obj.specificFunction1 and pass the result of previous map

// stream 2
StreamSupport
             .stream(myApi.getOtherData())
             .map(myfunctions:function)
             // at this point I want to invoke obj.specificFunction2 and pass the result of previous map
```

It would be great if those two stream could be somehow combined to make more sense. Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815221/java-8-apply-function-to-all-elements-of-stream-without-breaking-stream-chain

Comment: It depends of return result of your functions, if it's `void` than use `forEach`. If your function returns result, that should be collected- use `map` , than `collect`.